# Unexpected token on "?." in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have following code in typescript (with vue, but that is not related).

where "rules" can be undefined. So I wrote something like below. it gives error of "unexpected token" on "." after "?"

```
queryGroup.rules?.forEach
```

Now this is not showing as error in vs code, but shows error in visual studio.

I am using vue. so when I do "npm run build", it shows error and doesn't compile.

```
export interface QueryGroup {
    condition: Condition;
    rules?: Array<QueryRule | QueryGroup>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called optional chaining, available in typescript since 3.7 and soon be part of ECMA script also.

The statement `queryGroup.rules?.forEach((item) => {...})` will resolve to `undefined` when `queryGroup.rules` is null or undefined and not crash like without the `?`.

If you IDEs show errors, you probably have to fix their configuration so that they understands the typescript 3.7+ syntax. They probably use an older version of typescript internally or there's a language level setting.

Comment: yup. was using typescript 3.5